# Using a transition on the position with

Tags: javascript, html, css, lua, fivem

Basically, there are elements popping in when my armor is filled up, and I would need a transition for the position change because it just popping up is ugly! The only thing stopping me is I don't know shit about CSS but here's my code for it

```
#armor {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px; height: 30px; left: 50%; margin-top: 15px; transform: translateX(-50%);
    background-color: rgb(19, 19, 19);
    border-style: solid; border-width: 12px; border-color: rgb(19, 19, 19); border-radius: 50%; display: flex;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(103, 255, 194, 0.5);
    animation-name: fadein;
    animation-duration: 0.25s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

#armor .bar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px; height: 50%; bottom: 0;
    background-image: url("img/armor.png"); background-position: bottom; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; opacity: 1.0;
    transition: height 0.25s;
}

#armor .bg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px; height: 30px; bottom: 0;
    background-image: url("img/armor.png"); background-position: center; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; opacity: 0.2;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
   var oxygen = data.oxygen;
   var oxygenStatus = data.oxygenStatus
   document.getElementById('oxygen').getElementsByClassName('bar')[0].style.height = oxygen+"%"
   switch(armorStatus) {
        case true: 
            $("#armor").stop().fadeTo(400, 1)
        break;

        case false:
            $("#armor").fadeOut()
        break;
    }
```

I'm also using jQuery!

I already tried using transitions on the TOP and BOTTOM but it did not work.
Thanks for any help.

PREVIEWS:
First: https://prnt.sc/1gnqmfx
Second: https://prnt.sc/1gnqsc3

Comment: Sorry, I can't completely follow this - could you look at [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and put in a small example to illustrate the problem - that will have to include the HTML because at the moment I haven't a clue what elements are to 'pop up'.

Comment: So, if you want to do CSS animations, you can add e.g. transition: top 250ms; to the basic container with e.g. top: 25px. Then you could add a CSS class e.g. .animation with jQuery to the mentioned basic container and say like: #armor.animation { top: 125px; } Then the top value will be animated. But as Haworth said: could you be please a bit more specific? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to achive, so when one element fades out I don't want the others to just pop back I want them to move in to their position. Like this:
First Picture:
https://prnt.sc/1go1liy
Second Picture
https://prnt.sc/1go1xxr

The circle in red pops up when I'm running, but when I'm not running it disappears. and the circle below just pops back in, I want that to transition.

Comment: If it helps heres a video:
https://streamable.com/l63woe

Answer (score 0):

For this I suggest you look into using [CSS Transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

This will give you simplified control over the transitional effects, be more performant since you'll probably just be adding/removing a CSS class rather than animating the position of an element, and you'll benefit from hardware acceleration. ]

This is because transforms are an optimisation target for browsers, whereas actual positional offsets (top, left etc) are not, because these properties are expected to be static whereas you can tell the browser that the transform property is expected to change.

You can in fact "tell" the browser that an element property is going to change with the `will-change` CSS property (you can also use `transform: translate3d(x,y,z)` instead of `translate(x,y)` to trick the browser into using hardware acceleration).

Another advantage with the CSS approach is that it lets you keep the noise of defining animations out of your JavaScript, which can be preferable depending on the project.

Here's a really quick example:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    document.querySelector('.hidden').classList.toggle('shown');
});
```

```css
:root,body {overflow: hidden}
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.hidden {
  transform: translate3d(150%, 0, 0); /* <- starts off hidden, out of the viewport */
  will-change: transform;
  transition: .2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1); 
  /* 
    for the transition, you can use keywords like ease or linear, 
    or define your own timing function as above
  */
}

.shown {
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0); /* <- animating in is actually a case of resetting its translation (away from its origin) to 0 */
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden">
  I've moved into view with a CSS transform!
</div>

<button id="showDiv">
  Click to toggle the hidden element!
</button>
```

JSFiddle if preferred: https://jsfiddle.net/wnda/k4r51nfy/6/